# Where are the ground rods needed?

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

Drawing attached showing setup. [image]

Comment: What's the reasoning behind having that intermediate disconnect?  I take it the service disconnnecting means is on a pole or meter-board?

Comment: If you run a backhoe through that 112ft cable, and shorts it all together, will it melt the meter... Or will it trip a breaker in the left box?    Does anything *other* than a breaker exist at that pedestal main?

Comment: Are you in the US?

Comment: First box is a 200 amp mobile home service per permit. 2nd box is also a 200 amp main used as a junction box to connect the two runs of wire. 3rd box is the mobile home 200 amp main in the home.  Yes, shorted line between first 2 boxes would trip the main.

Answer (score 2):

At **minimum** you need a rod (or more usually 2, more than 8 feet part, since that gets you out of measuring the resistance cheaper than doing the measurement) at the entrance and the same at the mobile home. Given it's not a huge expense, buy 6 and sink a pair at the pedestal as well to be sure. No points off for doing more than the minimum.

*I have 5 or 6 and a 100 foot well casing on a single service entrance, personally.*

Comment: From  what I have read, the more ground rods used away from First disconnect increased the problems from lightening if I have understood right. The first first grounding rod is code here. I am confused.   Appreciate the comments and help.

Comment: If you are under NEC rules: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132502/is-it-bad-to-have-multiple-grounding-electrodes

Comment: Hey thanks, that explains it all and I only have one ground rod to move from pedestal to mobile home(out building)                                                                                                    Thanks to everyone that replied.